# Kiosk Mode - How do I get all files from a directory?

Tags: linux, kiosk

happy new year!

I have following problem:
I am using this shell script for the kiosk mode on my raspberry pi

```
\#!/bin/bash
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms

unclutter -idle 0.5 -root \&

sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /home/pi/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk /FolderX/file1.jpg /FolderX/file2.jpg /FolderX/file3.jpg &

whilte true; do
    xdotool keydown ctrl+Tab; xdotool keyup ctrl+Tab;
    sleep 10
done
```

When you look at the line that starts with /usr/bin.... you can see, that I am manually listing the files I want the Chromium Browser to open.
Now, all the files I need are in one folder "FolderX".
How do I need to change the script so that everytime all files inside of FolderX will be opened?
My goal is to not needing to type the file paths by hand, but if I move something in the folder the script will automatically take that file as well.

I am rookie in all of this, sorry!
Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to reference all files in *FolderX* by using [globs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), also known as "wildcards":

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-infobars --kiosk /FolderX/*
```

This should expand to "all files in /FolderX/".

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `/FolderX/file1.jpg /FolderX/file2.jpg /FolderX/file3.jpg` with `/FolderX/*`.

If you need to add another folder, add that folder like `/FolderX/* /anotherfolder/*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Way easier solution than I expected